# The number of subgroups of a cyclic group $G$ s.t. $|G| = pqr$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I know that if $|G|=n$, where $G$ is a cyclic group, then $G$ has a unique subgroup of order $d$ for each divisor of $n$. For the cyclic group $G$ whose order is $pqr$, such that each of $p$,$q$,$r$ is a distinct prime, how should I determine the number of subgroups including $\{id\}$ and $G$ itself?

Comment: This is an odd question, I think. Is it really that hard to try, at least, to count how many (positive) divisors the number $\;pqr\;$, for **different** primes $\;p,q,r\;$, has? You should really give it a serious try. The only real problem this question could pose is something you already know, namely: that a finite cyclic group has one unique subgroup of order any divisor of the group's order.

Comment: $1, p, q, r, pq, qr, pr, pqr$ - Then does it have only 8 subgroups? @DonAntonio

Comment: If it seems odd, I sincerely apologize... I just wonder too much whether I applied the lemma correctly, and I was not confident with my answer.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.